# Angular 5 listing ngFor while calling two linked object

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

So I have a `banks` array that looks like this:

```
[{id: 17, bankname: "A", account_number: "0609849432", branch: "",…},
{id: 114, bankname: "B", account_number: "1231241414", branch: null,…},
{id: 142, bankname: "A", account_number: "34234234", branch: null,…}]
```

I also have a `bank_image` array like this:

```
[{id: 4, bankname: "A", image: "www.foo.bar/imageA.jpg",…},
{id: 7, bankname: "B", image: "www.foo.bar/imageB.jpg",…},
{id: 14, bankname: "C", image: "www.foo.bar/imageC.jpg",…}]
```

For the view, I use `ngFor` to list the banks.
However, I also want to link the image from bank image array, so it looks like this.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of banks">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.account_number}}</td>
      <td>{{item.image}}</td>                 //how do I link the image?
</tr>
```

What is the proper way to get the image where `bank_image.name` == `banks.name`?

Desired output:

```
A    0609849432       www.foo.bar/imageA.jpg
B    1231241414       www.foo.bar/imageB.jpg
A    34234234         www.foo.bar/imageA.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution

```
banks = [{
    id: 17,
    bankname: "A",
    account_number: "0609849432",
    branch: ""
  },
  {
    id: 114,
    bankname: "B",
    account_number: "1231241414",
    branch: null
  },
  {
    id: 142,
    bankname: "A",
    account_number: "34234234",
    branch: null
  }
]

 bank_images = [{
    id: 4,
    bankname: "A",
    image: "www.foo.bar/imageA.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    bankname: "B",
    image: "www.foo.bar/imageB.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    bankname: "C",
    image: "www.foo.bar/imageC.jpg"
  }
]

getBankImage(bankname){
    let bankData=this.bank_images.find(data=>data.bankname==bankname);
    if(bankData){
      return bankData.image
    }
}
```

**and html code**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of banks">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.account_number}}</td>
      <td>{{getBankImage(item.bankname)}}</td> 
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Map your `banks` array to create a new one with all the properties you need, then use the new array in your HTML.

```js
const banks = [{
    id: 17,
    bankname: "A",
    account_number: "0609849432",
    branch: ""
  },
  {
    id: 114,
    bankname: "B",
    account_number: "1231241414",
    branch: null
  },
  {
    id: 142,
    bankname: "A",
    account_number: "34234234",
    branch: null
  }
]

const bank_images = [{
    id: 4,
    bankname: "A",
    image: "www.foo.bar/imageA.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    bankname: "B",
    image: "www.foo.bar/imageB.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    bankname: "C",
    image: "www.foo.bar/imageC.jpg"
  }
]

const newArr = banks.map(x => {
  return {
    ...x,
    image: bank_images.find(y => y.bankname === x.bankname).image
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write method to get image url by id, and call in template when needed. When hover or when click. If you need render image in table, then use map() aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Run a loop in your TS compare both arrays and create a new array from there which you would loop on your template via *ngFor